# Excecuting php when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So I've made a database where people can upload pictures to. The pictures are linked to a place which is linked to a category.

I'm trying to create a gallery page that displays all the images, and then the categories available. When you click on a category it's meant to show all the pictures for that category.

I've got my categories in my database as well, which I'm using php to echo out:

```
<?php
include('includes/connectdb.php');

/* Selects id and name from the table 'category' */
$query = "SELECT id, name FROM category";
$result_category = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
?>

<h1>Category</h1>
  <!-- iterate through the WHILE LOOP  -->
  <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_category)): ?>
    <!-- Echo out values {id} and {name}   -->
    <button name="category[]" value=" <?php echo $row['id']; ?> "><?php echo $row['name'] . '<br />'; ?></button>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

When a button is clicked I need it to run this php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['category[]'])){

displayimage();

function displayimage()
            {
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("ssdb",$con);
$qry="SELECT pictures.name, pictures.image, pictures.place_id
FROM pictures
INNER JOIN sted
ON pictures.place_id = sted.id
INNER JOIN placecategory
ON sted.id = placecategory.place_id
INNER JOIN category
ON placecategory.category_id = category.id
WHERE placecategory.category_id = $row['id']";

   $result=mysql_query($qry,$con);
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
        //var_dump($row); 
        echo '<img height="300" width="300" src="data:image;base64,'.$row["image"].' "> ';
        echo '<p style="display:inline-block">'.$row["name"].' </p> ';
      }
      mysql_close($con); 
    }
  }
  ?>
```

I found out that it should be possible with ajax, so I added the following to my ajax.php file:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case 'category':
            category();
            break;
    }
}
function category() {

displayimage();

      function displayimage()
            {
      $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
      mysql_select_db("ssdb",$con);
      $qry="SELECT pictures.name, pictures.image, pictures.place_id
FROM pictures
INNER JOIN sted
ON pictures.place_id = sted.id
INNER JOIN placecategory
ON sted.id = placecategory.place_id
INNER JOIN category
ON placecategory.category_id = category.id
WHERE placecategory.category_id = $row['id']";

      $result=mysql_query($qry,$con);
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
        //var_dump($row); 
        echo '<img height="300" width="300" src="data:image;base64,'.$row["image"].' "> ';
        echo '<p style="display:inline-block">'.$row["name"].' </p> ';
      }
      mysql_close($con); 
    }
    exit;
}
?>
```

And this to my gallery.php file where I'm displaying the pictures and categories.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
        var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
        var ajaxurl = 'ajax.php',
        data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
            // Response div goes here.
            alert("action performed successfully");
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And lastly I changed my button to be

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_category)): ?>
              <!-- Echo out values {id} and {name}   -->
              <input type="submit" class="button" name="category[]" value=" <?php echo $row['id']; ?> "><?php echo $row['name'] . '<br />'; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

I'm linking to the jquery library and I've tested the SQL statement that I need to run, and it works when I specify what the placecategory.category_id is.

Comment: same answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34185510/adding-a-click-function-to-elements-added-to-the-dom

Comment: @stephan so is it working now that you have used Ajax?